# CompletedStage.completedFuture VS CompletedStage.completedStage

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-9, completion-stage

I saw since Java9 CompletedStage.completedStage() is almost equals to CompletedStage.ompletedFuture()

When we must return

> `CompletionStage<Void>`

we can return both. CompletedFuture.completedFuture() is not deprecated and in Java doc for completedStage() it is written

```
Returns a new CompletionStage that is already completed with the given value and supports only 
those methods in interface CompletionStage.
```

So what is really the difference and when have to use one instead other ? when must return Void what is better ?

```
CompletedFuture.completedFuture(null)
```

or

```
CompletedFuture.completedStage(null)
```

Comment: There is no class `CompletedStage`

Comment: yes ok , but at the end what is difference ?

Comment: Funny that you changed the method name, but did not fix any of the reference to the non-existing class `CompletedStage`.